# What is the magnetization in a magnetic material, given an outside magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I have a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ which for simplicity I assume constant.
I put inside this field a magnetic material which is not magnetized yet.
Question: do I understand right that now the magnetization in material $\mathbf{M}$ is equal to $\mathbf{B}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $\mathbf{M}\neq \mathbf{B}$ ($\mathbf{B}$ being the magnetic flux density). It depends on the magnetic properties of the material which is characterised by a quantity $\chi$ called magnetic susceptibility. The simplest relationship between the magnetic field $\mathbf{H}$ and the magnetisation is linear (depending on the used measuring units and convention also $\mathbf{B}$ could be used instead of $\mathbf{H}$, actually there many different conventions in literature):

$$\mathbf{M} = \chi \mathbf{H}$$

Generally 3 types of materials distinguished, diamagnetic ones with $\chi<0$, paramagnetic ones $\chi>0$ and ferromagnetic ones where $\chi = \chi(\mathbf{H})$, i.e. in the last case the relationship is no longer linear. Such materials are characterised by a hysteresis curve which shows the dependence of $B$ as function of the applied $H$. Therefore the dependence can strongly non-linear or even anisotropic, i.e. $\chi$ varies inside the material, or $\chi$ can be even a tensor, i.e. the direction of the magnetisation is no longer the same than the one of the applied field. Possibly there are further special cases not mentioned.

Coming to your precise question, if the material is not magnetised yet and if it is not very special, i.e. neither anisotropic nor tensor-like susceptibility, the material is either diamagnetic or paramagnetic. So if there is no applied magnetic field, the magnetisation of the material would be zero.